# how to add time field in mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, model, database-schema

I'm creating a medicine reminder web app, that will require the user to enter the data related to medicine and the time at which the reminder will be shown.

So is there any way to store the **user input time in the mongodb**, there is a type to store date, but couldn't find anything to store time.

This is the **mongoose schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const medicineSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    count: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    about: {
        type: String
    },
    time: {
        type: TimeRanges,
        required: true
    }
}, { timestamps: true })

module.exports = mongoose.model('Medicine', medicineSchema)
```

I tried timeranges but it shows timeranges is not defined, and I don't think timeranges will store time input.

[Taking user input through the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtDxM.png)

Comment: You can either use the `Date` schema type or a `String` representing the time. `TimeRanges` is not a valid `SchemaType`. For more check https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Answer (score 0):

I am using [String SchemaType](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#strings) with [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

```
// Set current date TimeStamp, eg: '1666512804163'
TimeStamp: new Date().getTime().toString()

// Display saved TimeStamp, eg: '23/10/2022'
new Date(parseInt(TimeStamp)).toLocaleDateString()
```